# How do you change state with concatenating an ID on the end of state.go?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to change state to force a reload of the browser window but I need to make the url hold a id on the end.

```
   scope.takeAssessment = function (id) {
        state.go('app.tab.assessmentsDetails');
    };
```

This is the state that I'm trying to get to and as you can see I'm passing through an ID that ID needs to go on the end of the url to form something like below:

assessment/12312312312312 < (the numbers being the ID)

This is being called by a ng-click. There might be a better way to achieve what I want so please let me knwo in the comments below,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to pass params to state using `$state.go`, pass it as an object like below:

```
scope.takeAssessment = function (id) {
    $state.go('app.tab.assessmentsDetails', { id: id});
};
```

You can also use `ui-sref` directive to specify state and params and it will be converted to its corresponding `href`. E.g.:

```
<a ui-sref="app.tab.assessmentsDetails({id: id})">Take assessment</a>
```

Refer this for details: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#using-parameters-in-links

Comment: Happy to help :) Also, please accept/upvote the answer if it worked